# Overlapping between two elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, widget

I am new to CSS so please bear with me. I have widget that is positioned on the right, and i have created a RSS feed and a reader to read these feeds, now every feed is capsuled in div with class=rss
now the problem is that the div is visible under widget. I want the  to stop on the border of the widget and if there is no widget go full width, how can i achieve that.. here is a picture to demonstrate the situation:

[image]

here is my .rss code:

```
.rss {
background: #afb1b8;
border:1px dashed #ccc;
padding:5px;
}
```

here is widget code:

```
.widget {
     margin-bottom:20px;
}
.widget h2 {
     margin:0 0 10px 0;
     padding:0 5px;
     font-weight:normal;
     border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.widget .inner {
     margin:0 10px;
}
```

Please support your answers with code, and if it isn't too much please explain it to me. Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: Add the `body` background-color to the `.widget` and it will give the appearance of the `.rss` stopping at the widget's edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you don't want any part of a `.rss` div under the widget (the avatar in blueish grey)?

Then add `overflow: hidden` to your first rule. I guess the widget is positioned with `float: right`? Then `.rss` will play nice along with floats. You could replace `overflow: hidden` by `display: table`: both will give the div a [block formatting context](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/) (which is a very advanced topic in CSS, sorry for no further explanation here).

```
.rss {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #afb1b8;
  border:1px dashed #ccc;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Beware that `overflow: hidden` won't work as expected if you have dropdowns or anything that must display even slightly out of the area created by its element: nothing will be displayed (that's a good reason for a beginner not to use `overflow: hidden` in general)